# window.location is undefined when using Jest with rewire

Tags: jestjs, rewire

I'm writing tests for a file(some-file.js) that calls functions from another file(url-manipulator.js). I'm getting an error regarding window.location being undefined.  You can see in the error below that I logged window.location right before the error, and it is not undefined.  In jest.config.js I have configured the testEnvironment URL to https://www.something.com/ .  Any idea why this isn't carrying through when I rewire the urlManipulator file?

Error:

```
console.log
    window.location = https://www.something.com/ 
   
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'location')

1 | const urlManipulator = {
> 2 |       sHost: 'https://' + window.location.host,
```

Here is the start of my test file for some-file.js.  It's erroring out on this line const urlManipulatorJS = rewire("../../../head/js/url-manipulator") when it tries to read window.location from the url-manipulator file.

some-file.test.js

```
const rewire = require("rewire");
const file = rewire("../some-file");
const someFile = file.__get__("someFile");

console.log('window.location = ' +window.location);
const urlManipulatorJS = rewire("../../../head/js/url-manipulator");
const urlManipulator = urlManipulatorJS .__get__("urlManipulator");
file.__set__("urlManipulator", urlManipulator);
```

start of urlManipulator.js where it's failing

```
const urlManipulator= {
    sHost: 'https://' + window.location.host,
```

edit: adding jest.config.js settings to show that I'm using jsdom environment.

```
    testEnvironment: "jsdom",
    "testEnvironmentOptions": {
        "url": "https://www.something.com"
    },
```

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong test environment. By default, Jest runs in `node` environment.

Base on the latest Jest Doc, you can use the annotation to change it to `jsdom`, which should allow you to use `window`

```js
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

test('use jsdom in this test file', () => {
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  expect(element).not.toBeNull();
});
```

Alternatively, you can add the test environment to `jest.config.js`

Comment: I am using the jsdom test environment, which is set in jest.config.js

 testEnvironment: "jsdom",
 "testEnvironmentOptions": {
  "url": "https://www.something.com"
 },